# Colorize the map of Russia depending on the variable in R

Tags: r, maps

I have a map of Russia with regional subdivision

```
library(raster)
data <- getData('GADM', country='RUS', level=1)
```

http://www.gks.ru/bgd/regl/B16_14p/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d01/08-01.doc
The link is to a Word.doc with data (table) on crime rates for Russian regions. I can extract this data and use it in R. I want to take 2015 year and colorize regions on the map depending on the crime rate (also add a legend). How can I do this? The problem is that names of regions are sometimes different in the shape file (`NL_NAME_1`) and in the data from www.gks.ru. 
I also have this code for graph that I need, except that here we have meaningless colors:

```
library(sp) 
library(RColorBrewer)
data$region <- as.factor(iconv(as.character(data$NAME_1)))
spplot(data, "region", xlim=c(15,190), ylim=c(40,83),
   col.regions=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Set3"))(85), col = "white")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you just need to add your data to the spatial object for making colors meaningful.

Note, please, that the `data` is a reserved word in R. So, it's better to modify a little your variable name:

```
geo_data <- getData('GADM', country = 'RUS', level = 1)
```

Let's emulate some data to demonstrate a visualization strategy:

```
set.seed(23)
geo_data@data["data_to_plot"] <- sample(1:100, length(geo_data@data$NAME_1))
```

Using a default `GADM` projection would cut the most eastern part of the country. A simple transformation helps to fit the whole area to a plot:

```
# fit Russian area inside the plot
geo_data_trsf <- spTransform(geo_data, CRS("+proj=longlat +lon_wrap=180"))
```

Draw the map selecting `data_to_plot` instead of `region`:

```
max_data_val <- max(geo_data_trsf@data$data_to_plot)
spplot(geo_data_trsf, zcol = "data_to_plot",
   col.regions = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Set3"))(max_data_val), 
   col = "white")
```

The plot limits are adjusted automatically for the transformed spatial data `geo_data_trsf`, making possible to omit `xlim` and `ylim`.

As for the problem with the names, I can't provide any ready-to-use solution. Obviously, the regions' names of `NL_NAME_1` need some additional treatment to use them as labels. I think, it would be better to use `NAME_1` as an identifier in your code to ensure that it'll be no troubles with encoding. The `NL_NAME_1` column is perfectly suitable to set the correspondence between your `Word-data` and the data inside the spatial object `geo_data`.